# HEIC to JPEG from say quick actions right click

Tags: catalina, image-editing, heic

I would want to right click on HEIC file and be presented with options to save as JPEG; maybe a quick action?

Answer (score 1):

[image: capture of finder with quick action convert image]

I have that quick action available to me that's just called "Convert Image" that works great. I also made a quick action in automator called HEIC to JPG.

I made you a screen capture of what that workflow looks like.

[image: capture of automator quick action]

Comment: Well found. I'd looked & didn't see that one, only the GraphicConverter one.

Comment: This works to an extent. If I remove Duplicate Finder Items, it overwrites original. If I keep, it copies, and then makes another copy for the JPEG. strange.

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to install Homebrew and Magick and Perl, looks like m-graf setup potential solution:

https://gist.github.com/m-graf/ab76972ebba4170dbefc794d1afe95f9

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.